# Typescript casting object to a class ignoring properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that I am trying to cast from my webapi call.

So lets say this is the data from the webapi

```
let userTestStatus: { id: number, name: string }[] = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "Available", "date" : "01/01/2001" },
    { "id": 1, "name": "Ready", "date" : "01/01/2001" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Started", "date" : "01/01/2001" }
];
```

This is my typescript Class. As you can see there is no date property

```
export myClass{
  id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

When the object is converted the date property is there even though it doesn't exist in my class. How can I get typescript to ignore properties that do not exist in the class?

Comment: I guess with `Array.prototype.map()` you can restructure your array.

Comment: Casting is typescript\s feature. It doesnt work in runtime, only on compile time. And casting's purpose to help you avoid mistakes, not mutate data

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius so what can we use to mutate data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map all of your objects just to such model which you would like to have

```
const myModelObejctsArray: MyModel[] = userTestStatus.map(user => {
   return {
    id: user.id,
    name: user.name
   }
})
```

Comment: This I like. Does exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Your data fulfills the given type interface.
However, your data has even more properties than you declared as a type.

Your Typescript IDE should display you some message that the objects in your array do not specifically have a date property. But you can still run it.

If you do not want the date property in your array elements, you could delete it on your own:

```
userTestStatus.forEach(e => delete e.date);
```

Comment: Now what if the data is dynamic coming in from the webapi? How could we delete or ignore properties that do not exist in the typescript class?

Comment: You would in almost all cases build your data like @Stefan's answer.
Because you cannot explicitly delete something you do not know is actually there.